# Calculate SHA1 hash from binary and verify with a provided hash

Tags: python, algorithm, interview-questions

I applied for a job and they asked me to write code with the following requirements:

> Get a "toolbar offer" description from
>   http..update.utorrent.com/installoffer.php?offer=conduit.  Parse the
>   bencoded (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bencode) response and
>   extract the URL of the binary and its SHA1 hash.  The hash is contained
>   in the value of the key 'offer_hash'. The binary is in list for the
>   key 'offer_urls' — please use the one prefixed with
>   "http..download.utorrent.com/".
>
> Download the binary and calculate its hash
>
> Verify that the calculated SHA1 hash is identical to the one provided
>   in the offer details.  It is okay to use existing libraries for
>   bencoding, hashing, etc.

What is wrong with my code? The recruiter said it didn't meet their bar.

```
# Script that verifies the correctness of a toolbar offers

import urllib, bencode , hashlib
from hashlib import sha1

url = "http://update.utorrent.com/installoffer.php?offer=conduit"

filename = "content.txt"

f= urllib.urlretrieve(url, filename)

#Bdecoding the response

with open (str(filename), 'rb') as myfile:
           data=myfile.read()
           decoded = bencode.bdecode(data)

# Returning the list for the key 'offer_urls'


list = decoded['offer_urls']

#print list


# Returning the URL of the binary that is prefixed with "http://download3.utorrent.com/"

length = len (list)

prefix = "http://download3.utorrent.com/"

i= -1

while i < length:
     i = i + 1
     if list[i].startswith(prefix) :
        break
binary= list[i]

print "The URL of the the binary is: " , binary


# Returning the sha1 hash contained in the value of the key 'offer_hash'


encrypted_hash = decoded['offer_hash']
sha1_hash1 = encrypted_hash.encode('hex')
print "The sha1 hash contained in the value of the key 'offer_hash' is: " , sha1_hash1 


# Downloading the binary and calculating its hash

urllib.urlretrieve ( binary , "utct2-en-conduit-20130523.exe")
file = "C:\Python27\utct2-en-conduit-20130523.exe"
with open (file, 'rb') as myfile:
           downloaded=myfile.read()

k = hashlib.sha1()
k.update(downloaded)
sha1file = k.hexdigest()
print "The sha1 hash of the downloaded binary is: " , sha1file

# Verify that the calculated sha1 hash is identical to the one provided in the offer details

if (sha1file == sha1_hash1) :
    print "Test result = Pass"
else :
    print "Test result = Fail"
```

Comment: A fairly simple problem with your code: Comments should explain why, not how.

Comment: It does show your a pragmatist which is good when your working alone.

Answer (score 370):

I'm going to tell you the things in your code that made me wonder.

```
# Script that verifies the correctness of a toolbar offers

import urllib, bencode , hashlib
```

Extra space after `bencode` suggests lack of attention to detail.

```
from hashlib import sha1

url = "http://update.utorrent.com/installoffer.php?offer=conduit"

filename = "content.txt"

f= urllib.urlretrieve(url, filename)
```

Use of single-letter variables suggests lack of attention to clean code.

```
#Bdecoding the response

with open (str(filename), 'rb') as myfile:
```

`filename` is already a string.  Converting it to a string again suggests confusion as to what is going on.

```
           data=myfile.read()
           decoded = bencode.bdecode(data)
```

Massive indentation suggests disregard for consistent indentation style.

Downloading the file to disk then reading it into memory is poor use of available APIs. You should download the file directly into memory.

```
# Returning the list for the key 'offer_urls'
```

Excess whitespace suggests someone is enter-happy.

```
list = decoded['offer_urls']
```

"Returning" is technically incorrect here. You aren't in a function, so you aren't returning anything. Use of `list` is a bad name for a variable since it's a built-in Python type.

```
#print list


# Returning the URL of the binary that is prefixed with "http://download3.utorrent.com/"

length = len (list)
```

Putting spaces after function calls is odd, and you don't do it consistently. There's also rarely a good reason to store the length of a `list`.

```
prefix = "http://download3.utorrent.com/"

i= -1
```

No space before the `=`.

```
while i < length:
     i = i + 1
     if list[i].startswith(prefix) :
        break
binary= list[i]
```

You are using a `while` loop when you should be using a `for` loop. It is also going to cause an `IndexError`, rather than fail gracefully, if the prefix isn't found.

```
print "The URL of the the binary is: " , binary


# Returning the sha1 hash contained in the value of the key 'offer_hash'


encrypted_hash = decoded['offer_hash']
```

Is that hash really encrypted?

```
sha1_hash1 = encrypted_hash.encode('hex')
print "The sha1 hash contained in the value of the key 'offer_hash' is: " , sha1_hash1 


# Downloading the binary and calculating its hash

urllib.urlretrieve ( binary , "utct2-en-conduit-20130523.exe")
file = "C:\Python27\utct2-en-conduit-20130523.exe"
```

Hard-coded filename will be easy to break. You shouldn't even need to do it. The string also contains `"\"` which should be escaped, or the whole string should be raw. i.e.

```
"C:\\Python27\\utct2-en-conduit-20130425.exe"
```

or

```
r"C:\Python27\utct2-en-conduit-20130425.exe"
```

or in most cases you can use the other slashes, even on Windows.

```
"C:/Python27/utct2-en-conduit-20130425.exe"
```

You got away with what you did, but that's mostly because you are lucky.

```
with open (file, 'rb') as myfile:
           downloaded=myfile.read()
```

This last piece of code did pretty much the same thing as a previous bit of code, but you didn't use a function.

```
k = hashlib.sha1()
k.update(downloaded)
sha1file = k.hexdigest()
print "The sha1 hash of the downloaded binary is: " , sha1file

# Verify that the calculated sha1 hash is identical to the one provided in the offer details

if (sha1file == sha1_hash1) :
```

You've put parentheses, which are not necessary.

```
    print "Test result = Pass"
else :
    print "Test result = Fail"
```

Your basic problems:

1. Your style is poor and inconsistent
2. A few things suggest you don't quite understand what's going on
3. You haven't taken care to make the code readable

Here's my take on the problem:

```
# Script that verifies the correctness of a toolbar offers

import urllib
import bencode
import hashlib
import contextlib

# it's common practice to put input details like this
# as global constants at the start of your script
URL = "http://update.utorrent.com/installoffer.php?offer=conduit"
PREFIX = "http://download3.utorrent.com/"

# by breaking down your task into functions
# you can make the code easier to follow
def read_bencoded_url(url):
    with contextlib.closing(urllib.urlopen(url)) as offer_file:
        return bencode.bdecode(offer_file.read())

def find_string_with_prefix(strings, prefix):
    for string in strings:
        if string.startswith(prefix):
            return string
    else:
        raise Exception("Did not find prefix: {}".format(prefix))

# this function is a bit more complicated
# but it avoids saving the file to disk or loading it entirely into memory.
# instead it hashes it 4096 bytes at a time
def hash_of_url(url):
    hasher = hashlib.sha1()
    with contextlib.closing(urllib.urlopen(url)) as binary_file:
        while True:
            data = binary_file.read(4096)
            if not data:
                break
            hasher.update(data)
    return hasher.hexdigest()

# the actual high level logic just calls the functions
# this avoid obscuring the logic with lower level details
def main():
    decoded = read_bencoded_url(URL)
    binary = find_string_with_prefix(decoded['offer_urls'], PREFIX)
    reported_hash = decoded['offer_hash'].encode('hex')
    actual_hash = hash_of_url(binary)
    print "The sha1 hash contained in the value of the key 'offer_hash' is: ", reported_hash
    print "The sha1 hash of the downloaded binary is: " , actual_hash

    if reported_hash == actual_hash:
        print "Test result = Pass"
    else:
        print "Test result = Fail"

if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

Comment: Still some things to do. Imports per line, or at least fix your first own comment. High level logic in a function called main please the check if its teh main module and run main this way its easier to reuse the code. PS I presume the comments are for the benefit of OP and most not to be included in the actual submission ;)

Comment: Harsh... but very well done. Hopefully just what the doctor ordered.

Comment: @joojaa, you are of course correct. I didn't address those because I'd wouldn't necessarily assume a poor coder on those alone. But i've gone ahead and done so now.

Comment: Actually, one of the comments shouldn't be there at all, the one directly before the part comparing the hashes.  That comment does not contribute to making the code easier to understand.

Comment: I was really confused by this answer until I realized I wasn't on StackOverflow anymore.

Comment: I wouldn't ding him on the extra parens.  When you're dealing with multiple languages it's good to be defensive with paren usage, extra ones do no harm.

Comment: @LorenPechtel, What? I need those two extra bytes of disk space! :P The parens aren't a serious issue, but they might indicative of confusion about the language.

Comment: I don't think this is too harsh by any means. If you upload your code, you should be GRATEFUL for a critique this thorough. Well done!

Comment: In your `hash_of_url` you can replace the ugly `while True` + `break` with a `for` + `iter(callable, sentinel)`: `for chunk in iter(lambda: binary_file.read(4096), ''): hasher.update(chunk)`

Comment: @Bakuriu, I'm not sure I like that better. I'll agree that `while True/break` is ugly. Regardless, probably more complexity than the OP needs right now.

Comment: Note that the requirements specified to download the file.  I'd interpret that to mean it should reside on disk when the program exits, which this code avoids.

Comment: @AlanShutko, hmm.. I wouldn't interpret the requirements that way. Furthermore, it doesn't really seem to make sense in the scope of the question to want the file left on disk. But that's why you should clarify in the face of ambiguity.

Comment: @WinstonEwert: Thanks a lot for taking the time to provide me with such a detailed answer!! It really helped!

Comment: Amazing answer. Well done @WinstonEwert

Comment: Made my day proves that there are good skilled people who can take time to read and answer your problem

Comment: *You did not just* `raise Exception()`.

Comment: When you say “Downloading the file to disk then reading it into memory is poor use of available APIs. You should download the file directly into memory.” would that look like this: decoded = bencode.bdecode(myfile) ?

Comment: @RobertHoughton, that depends on where `myfile` came from. To see how I'd do it, see my version of the code at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 65):

Run your code through [pep8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8) and possibly a more pedantic static analyzer like [pylint](http://www.logilab.org/857#projectinfo_tab).

You will find these tools don't like some of your formatting and variable names. They will likely complain there are too many variables, branches, etc. because the code is not broken up into modularized functions.

Answer (score 44):

If I was to take your code then multiply it out 100 or a thousand times into other files (the size of a regular commercial/enterprise application then it would be a dog's breakfast and not maintainable at all.

You need to take more care with your code and make it readable and consistent. Think of it as formatting your resume for a potential employer. Use consistent whitespace between characters, consistent comments above the code (not multiple line breaks between) and above all adopt one of the common style guides for the language. Winston posted an excellent example earlier.

This shows you can at least write code that reads and presents well. If you're coding in a professional environment, other people have to read the code you wrote as well and they need to understand it quickly. If they're scanning through the code then suddenly there's a random comment floating in the page it's a real distraction.

A good book to read is [Clean Code by Robert Martin](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132350882). You must read this as if your life depended on it.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/859/ )

Answer (score 30):

Problems:

1. I would say that `import` should be an efficient way of reusing the libraries.

   ```
   import urllib, bencode , hashlib
   from hashlib import sha1
   ```

   In the above line of code you have imported `hashlib` and `sha1` from `hashlib` on the second line. There is nothing wrong in that, but when you just want to use only `sha1`, then no need to import the entire class.

   Same with other classes: how many members of the above mentioned libraries have you used in your code?
2. All the constants should be predefined at the beginning of the script, not wherever required.
3. What if the above file failed to open (in case file not present)?  How do you deal with this exception?

   ```
   with open (str(filename), 'rb') as myfile:
          downloaded=myfile.read()
   ```

   Use try-except to catch exceptions.
4. Filename is already a string.
5. No need to use an extra variable to store the length of the list.  Also there is a space in between the function `len` and its arg.

   ```
   length = len (list)
   ```
6. Use a `for` loop for indexing, which is better than using a `while` loop.
7. Meaningless variable names such as `i`, `f`, `k`.
8. The tasks are not well-divided into different subroutines.

Comment: Problem 8 is the biggest problem. His solution is a typical case of a `transactional script`. I hate transactional scripts, and others do too.